# Discord.py, requests Aren't not working for me

Tags: python-requests, discord.py

My problem is a bot I made from discord.py, I am preparing a bot for a tournament called https://sploop.io. I get it from https://account.sploop.io/rankingScore url using requests. It starts as #1 from the bottom and ends at #600 to the top. The right part is the user's id. The middle part is the user's username. . everything else is working fine.

Code :

```py
@bot.command()
async def whois(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    user_id = member.id
    found = False

    def get_user_data(hashtag):
        url = "https://account.sploop.io/rankingScore"

        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()

        for user in data:
            if user[2] == hashtag:
                score = user[0]
                leaderboard_username = user[1]
                position = data.index(user) + 1
                return score, leaderboard_username, position

        return None, None, None

    with open("linkaccount.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if f"Discord={user_id}" in line:
                found = True
                info = line.split(", ")
                rank_account = info[3].split("=")[1]
                hashtag = info[4].split("=")[1]
                game_username = info[5].split("=")[1]
                region = info[2].split("=")[1]
                score, leaderboard_username, position = get_user_data(hashtag)

                if score is not None:
                    await ctx.reply(f"Discord Username: {member.name}\nRegion: {region}\nRank Account: {rank_account}\nHashtag: {hashtag}\nGame Username: {game_username}\nLeaderboard Rank: {position}\nLeaderboard Score: {score}\nUsername: {leaderboard_username}")
                else:
                    await ctx.reply(f"Discord Username: {member.name}\nRegion: {region}\nRank Account: {rank_account}\nHashtag: {hashtag}\nGame Username: {game_username}\nUser not found in the leaderboard.")
                break

    if not found:
        await ctx.reply("Account not found.")
```

In this part, the bot says that it is not included in the leaderboard because the request does not work. is normally the second of the game.

I want to put everything received from https://account.sploop.io/rankingScore in a bot by making a Request. if leaderboard then works this code
await ctx.reply(f"Discord Username: {member.name}\nRegion: {region}\nRank Account: {rank_account}\nHashtag: {hashtag}\nGame Username: {game_username}\nLeaderboard : { position}\nLeaderboard Score: {score}\nUsername: {leaderboard_username}") will work

if not in the leaderboard
await ctx.reply(f"Discord Username: {member.name}\nRegion: {region}\nRank Account: {rank_account}\nHashtag: {hashtag}\nGame Username: {game_username}\nUser not found in the leaderboard." )

If the problem is that it will work, the user says it is on the leaderboard but not on the leaderboard, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using library such as aiohttp instead of requests for asynchronous calls, especially for a discord bot.

You could refactor your get_user_data function using aiohttp like this:

```
import aiohttp

async def get_user_data(hashtag):
    url = "https://account.sploop.io/rankingScore"

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                for user in data:
                    if user[2] == hashtag:
                        return user[0], user[1], data.index(user) + 1

    return None, None, None
```

As for other problems, I would suggest checking if `user[2]` value is in the leaderboard.

Comment: When I tried the command was not working when I did it differently I got this error
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sploop events\main.py", line 99
    score, leaderboard_username, position = get_user_data(hashtag)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_user_data' was never awaited

Well, would it be okay if you just give the direct code?

Comment: @İlyax because when you call an async function, you need to use `await` keyword to call it (if you do this in another async function).